# how to disable turbo links completely from rails

Tags: sprockets, ruby-on-rails-5, turbolinks, rails-sprockets

I've gone through quite a few posts and turbolinks documentation, and I think I haven't quite got it yet. I'm trying to completely turn off turbolinks in rails 5 application. Here's how I went about it

1. Removed `gem 'trubolinks'`
2. removed all occurrences of `//=require turbolinks` from application.js
3. removed `data-turbolinks-track` from `stylesheet_link_tag` and `javascript_include_tag`

The application.html.erb now looks like this

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title><%= content_for?(:title) ? yield(:title) : "Website" %></title>
    <meta name="description" content="<%= content_for?(:description) ? yield(:description) : "Website" %>">
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all' %>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag params[:controller]  %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag :modernizr %>    
    <%= javascript_include_tag params[:controller] %>
    <%= if(params[:action].eql?'contact')
          javascript_include_tag 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=vcRecaptchaApiLoaded&render=explicit' , async: 'async',  defer: 'defer' 
        end
    %>  
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
  </head>
  <body data-turbolinks='false'>
     ...
  </body>
</html>
```

the application.js file:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require lodash
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require jquery.sticky
```

and application.css

```
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap"; 
@import "font-awesome-sprockets";
@import "font-awesome"; 
@import "normalize-rails";
@import "animate";
.... 
/* other css stuff */
```

I was thinking using `data-turbolinks=false` on body tag should help disable it for all pages in this layout. But that hasn't helped, the pages fail to load with error

```
Sprockets::FileNotFound at /
couldn't find file 'turbolinks' with type 'application/javascript'
Checked in these paths: 
  /Users/anadi/Code/website/app/assets/config
  /Users/anadi/Code/website/app/assets/fonts
  /Users/anadi/Code/website/app/assets/images
  /Users/anadi/Code/website/app/assets/javascripts
```

at this line on the home page

`<%= image_tag("pages/home/xyz_logo.png", class: "img-responsive", alt: "Customer") %>`

if I look at the stack trace, ActionView invariably depends on turbolinks:

```
  sprockets (3.7.0) lib/sprockets/directive_processor.rb:182:in `rescue in block in process_directives'
  sprockets (3.7.0) lib/sprockets/directive_processor.rb:179:in `block in process_directives'
  sprockets (3.7.0) lib/sprockets/directive_processor.rb:178:in `process_directives'
  sprockets (3.7.0) lib/sprockets/directive_processor.rb:83:in `_call'
  sprockets (3.7.0) lib/sprockets/directive_processor.rb:68:in `call'
  sprockets (3.7.0) lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:75:in `call_processor'
  sprockets (3.7.0) lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:57:in `block in call_processors'
  sprockets (3.7.0) lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `call_processors'
  sprockets (3.7.0) lib/sprockets/loader.rb:134:in `load_from_unloaded'
  sprockets (3.7.0) lib/sprockets/loader.rb:60:in `block in load'
  sprockets (3.7.0) lib/sprockets/loader.rb:317:in `fetch_asset_from_dependency_cache'
  sprockets (3.7.0) lib/sprockets/loader.rb:44:in `load'
  sprockets (3.7.0) lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:20:in `block in initialize'
  sprockets (3.7.0) lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:47:in `load'
  sprockets (3.7.0) lib/sprockets/bundle.rb:23:in `block in call'
  sprockets (3.7.0) lib/sprockets/utils.rb:196:in `dfs'
  sprockets (3.7.0) lib/sprockets/bundle.rb:24:in `call'
  sprockets (3.7.0) lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:75:in `call_processor'
  sprockets (3.7.0) lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:57:in `block in call_processors'
  sprockets (3.7.0) lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `call_processors'
  sprockets (3.7.0) lib/sprockets/loader.rb:134:in `load_from_unloaded'
  sprockets (3.7.0) lib/sprockets/loader.rb:60:in `block in load'
  sprockets (3.7.0) lib/sprockets/loader.rb:317:in `fetch_asset_from_dependency_cache'
  sprockets (3.7.0) lib/sprockets/loader.rb:44:in `load'
  sprockets (3.7.0) lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:20:in `block in initialize'
  sprockets (3.7.0) lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:47:in `load'
  sprockets (3.7.0) lib/sprockets/base.rb:66:in `find_asset'
  sprockets (3.7.0) lib/sprockets/base.rb:73:in `find_all_linked_assets'
  sprockets (3.7.0) lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:134:in `block in find'
  sprockets (3.7.0) lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:133:in `find'
  sprockets-rails (3.1.1) lib/sprockets/railtie.rb:50:in `precompiled_assets'
  sprockets-rails (3.1.1) lib/sprockets/railtie.rb:35:in `asset_precompiled?'
  sprockets-rails (3.1.1) lib/sprockets/railtie.rb:250:in `block (3 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
  sprockets-rails (3.1.1) lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:342:in `precompiled?'
  sprockets-rails (3.1.1) lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:346:in `raise_unless_precompiled_asset'
  sprockets-rails (3.1.1) lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:313:in `asset_path'
  sprockets-rails (3.1.1) lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:85:in `block in resolve_asset_path'
  sprockets-rails (3.1.1) lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:225:in `block in resolve_asset'
  sprockets-rails (3.1.1) lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:224:in `resolve_asset'
  sprockets-rails (3.1.1) lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:84:in `resolve_asset_path'
  sprockets-rails (3.1.1) lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:74:in `compute_asset_path'
  actionview (5.0.0) lib/action_view/helpers/asset_url_helper.rb:144:in `asset_path'
  actionview (5.0.0) lib/action_view/helpers/asset_url_helper.rb:311:in `image_path'
  actionview (5.0.0) lib/action_view/helpers/asset_tag_helper.rb:214:in `image_tag'
```

It looks like sprockets still expects turbolinks js or the image_tag url expects it. I don't want to end-up adding a `data: { turbolinks: false }` on every link or image. How to get this working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was doing it wrong perhaps, re-enabled all of it, added `data-turbolinks-track => true` also, and preserved `<body data-turbolinks='false'>`. It works as expected now without throwing errors.

Answer (score 1):

1. Remove the gem 'turbolinks' line from your Gemfile.
2. Remove the //= require turbolinks from your app/assets/javascripts/application.js.
3. Remove the two "data-turbolinks-track" => true hash key/value pairs
   from your app/views/layouts/application.html.erb.

Comment: If you look at the code shared I've done all that already! :-)